# How to list/delete Clients in Aqueduct auth?

Tags: client, aqueduct

I'm following the Aqueduct docs for auth  and I see that a Client is added like so:

```
aqueduct auth add-client \
  --id com.food_app.mobile \
  --connect postgres://user:password@dbhost:5432/food_app
```

How do I check what ClientId I registered? I can't find how to delete or list registered ClientIds..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check your database. The table is `_authclient` look for the `id` column. You can delete the registered client by just deleting the row from the table.

For an easy GUI for postgres if you're on a mac i recommend [postico](https://eggerapps.at/postico/)

Comment: Sweet. Thank you very much.